# Python GTK GUI for YouTube-DL show progress in window

Tags: python, gtk3, youtube-dl

I am currently working on my own YouTube-DL GTK GUI in Python. I would like to display the download progress by reading it out of the YouTube-DL progress hook. if I do this as below, it will only be displayed as 100% at the end of the download.
Why doesn't it update during the download?

```
        def my_hook(d):
            if d['status']      == 'downloading':
               self.label.set_text("Fortschritt:"+d['_percent_str']+"Verbleibende Zeit:"+d['_eta_str'])
                
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': (Art),
            'outtmpl': (Out),
            'noplaylist': (self.playlist),
            'extract-audio': (audio),
            'progress_hooks': [my_hook],
        }
        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download([URL])
```

Comment: I have implemented an example about how to use the hook to update a progressbar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75963054/how-to-update-a-progress-bar-in-pygtk-with-the-download-percentage-provided-by/76010522#76010522

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using threads to download? In my own tk program, this works completely fine and updates as I expect it would, but that may be a possible solution.

https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32103997)